# Saving buffer with a 16-bit floating point texture

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, core-graphics

I cannot find a combination of parameters that works with float (I managed to save with unsigned byte):

```
float *rawImagePixels = (float*)malloc(width * height * sizeof(float));
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RED_EXT, GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES, rawImagePixels);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:rawImagePixels length:width*height];
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width, height, 16, 16, width, colorspace, kCGImageAlphaNone|kCGBitmapByteOrder16Big, provider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, self, nil, nil);
```

My texture is a 1-channel half float texture. How can I save it as a UIImage?

Comment: For a half float, you probably don't want 4-byte alignment (which is the default, by the way) -- you probably want 2-byte. Are you running into problems with the image being sort of slanted by any chance? *Because that would be indicative of incorrect alignment.*

Comment: I get output that seem to make sense now (see update), but not sure about the intensities and there are black squares here and there.

Comment: Any chance you could include a screenshot of the output image? I'm not sure what you're using floating-point for here, but if it's HDR then you have to consider how you display values outside the range [**0.0**,**1.0**]. If you try to display a floating-point image you generally need to remap / normalize the values.

Comment: I have a *disparity map* and I want to save it. The main problem was it was coming from a half-float texture. When I sorted out the conversion from half-float to float, after `glReadPixels`, it became easier to save the image, in 32bit float format.

Comment: I only took a cursory glance at your problem, which is why I didn't attempt an answer—rather, pointing you to this: https://demonicactivity.blogspot.com/2016/11/tech-serious-ios-developers-use-every.html Maybe you can cobble something together from it.

Answer (score 0):

**Extracted from the question**

I got semi-decent results with this code:

```
GLhalf *rawImagePixels = (GLhalf*)malloc(width * height * sizeof(GLhalf));
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 2);
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RED_EXT, GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES, rawImagePixels);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:rawImagePixels length:width * height * sizeof(GLhalf)];
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
int bitsPerComponent = 16, bitsPerPixel = 16, bytesPerRow = width * 2;
CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorspace, kCGImageAlphaNone|kCGBitmapByteOrder16Little, provider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, self, nil, nil);
```